# For home chemistry purposes can you treat sodium percarbonate as sodium peroxide?

Tags: home-experiment

It is easy to find home chemistry experiments for sodium peroxide but not so much sodium percarbonate. Industrially sodium percarbonate is used a sodium peroxide source- it is close enough to used as a substitute for common home experiments?

Comment: you really need to specify what experiment you want to do.

Comment: Sorry my addled brain thought I was writing hydrogen peroxide

Comment: Then fix it in the question title/body, otherwise readers will take it as the valid content. (Fixing it on the author behalf is always a risk not to match what the author has in mind .). // In the current question wording, the answer is it cannot be said until the particular scenario is specified.

Comment: It is not a true peroxoacid anion like persulphate or peracetate. It is a peroxohydrate, releasing free hydrogen peroxide when dissolved, or at contact with suitable solvent.

Answer (score 3):

These behave fairly differently, in most cases. Look at the Safety Data Sheets, first:

- [$\ce{Na2O2}$, sodium peroxide](https://www.fishersci.com/store/msds?partNumber=AC207700250&productDescription=SODIUM%20PEROXIDE%2C%20P.A.%2025GR&vendorId=VN00032119&countryCode=US&language=en):

  ```
  This chemical is considered hazardous by... 29 CFR 1910.1200
  Skin Corrosion/Irritation Category 1A
  Oxidizing solids Category 1
  ```
- [$\ce{Na2CO3.1.5 H2O2}$, sodium percarbonate](http://www.integrachem.com/msds/S510_26444_101.pdf):

  ```
  This chemical is considered hazardous by... 29 CFR 1910.1200
  Acute oral toxicity Category 4
  Oxidizing solids Category 3
  ```

$\ce{Na2O2}$ is a more powerful oxidizer, more likely to start combustion in contact with organic substances, can cause skin corrosion, and is generally not very stable.

$\ce{Na2CO3.1.5 H2O2}$ is a less powerful oxidizer, a bit more stable, less toxic orally, and is **not** listed as corrosive to skin (caustic), just possibly irritating.

Yes, both can be used as a source of oxygen, $\ce{O2}$, but $\ce{Na2O2}$ can react abruptly, perhaps causing a conflagrating explosion. In some use, the water and $\ce{CO2}$ that accompany evolution of oxygen from $\ce{Na2CO3.1.5 H2O2}$ might interfere with a reaction.

*Caveat pharmacopolium:* It is *possible*, if you have the chemical and engineering knowledge, to use one in place of the other in *some* situations... but you'd need to be specific to get any assurance.